# Can't find AD data connection when importing pictures from AD

Tags: 2013, active-directory, profile-sync, ad

I want to syncronize the pictures in AD with SharePoint 2013, but I can't seem to find the AD data connection. I'm following [this guide](http://richardstk.com/2013/04/12/import-user-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2013/).

But when I go to select the AD data connection when adding a **New** mapping, the dropdown is just blank. What's the problem and how can I solve this?

The SP13 solution in general seems to work good with AD.

Answer (score 1):

The source data connection drop-down includes your Active Directory import source, i.e. you need to have already configured a user import from Active Directory. This is done from `Manage Profile Service -> Configure Synchronization Connections`.

Comment: I get "Cannot navigate to the requested page because User Profile Synchronization service is not running. Please start the User Profile Synchronization service before creating a connection". But I am having problems starting it. User Profile Synchronization just stops right away. I try to start it as the farm service account, and the service account is local admin. But still nothing. Why is this?

Comment: if service is stuck on starting or stopping that's a different problem all together. That means your AD is not getting synchronized with SharePoint